# Try to Format the []slice into specific format

Tags: json, string, go, slice

Hello I am new in Go before that i was working as JavaScript developer

**i am getting info variable as []string from rabbitMq and passing into that some another function
That function will do some external api call , when i try to hit with Postman with same data what i am getting from rabbitMq from my codebase it is working as expected but when i try do hit that api with the help of golang http call i am facing issue attaching screenshot of postman request postman code , my codebase and Print of info variable and my rabbitMq data**     [Image of postman api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFNT9.png)  [Image of postman api request code with Golang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsgjT.png)   [image of rabbitMq queue data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLTpz.png)   [Print of info variable under my function to check what info is cominga s request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGBIt.png)      [Codebase to hit external api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkhFz.png)

Comment: Your "info variable" is not valid Go. Share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @EmilePels please check the screenshot and let me know if you want more infomation

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MarshalIndent`. The second argument is a prefix (if you need more `\n` you can put it here) and the last argument is the indent character (as I put it `\t`).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    info := []map[string]interface{}{
        {"eventType": "MyEvent", "account": 5, "amount": 7000000, "product": "Dairy"},
    }

    r, e := json.MarshalIndent(info, "", "\t")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)        
    }
    
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%q", string(r)))
}

// output: "[\n\t{\n\t\t\"account\": 5,\n\t\t\"amount\": 7000000,\n\t\t\"eventType\": \"MyEvent\",\n\t\t\"product\": \"Dairy\"\n\t}\n]"
```

Comment: `func MakeHTTPRequest(info []string) {
 fmt.Println(info, "INFO_COMING FROM RABBITMQ CONSUMER")
 r, e := json.MarshalIndent(info, "", "\t")
 if e != nil {
  panic(e)
 }
 url := "https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/2914304/events"
 method := "POST"
 payload := strings.NewReader(string(r))
 client := &http.Client{}
 req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

 req.Header.Add("X-Insert-Key", "NRII-XvzF4teEV6YwgWMdWwwk1niD2W77abuu")
 req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
 res, err := client.Do(req)
}`

Comment: above is my scenario the info variable is coming as **[]string** please help me if you can  printing info for your refrence `[ {
    "eventType":"PriceEvent",
    "account":5,
    "amount":7000000,
    "product":"Jha"
  }] INFO_COMING FROM RABBITMQ CONSUMER`

Comment: please check the screenshot i have attached in my question for your reference and help me if you can Thanks in adavnce